# Wait until all background jobs have terminated, C

Tags: process, fork, wait, pid

I know how waitpid(-1...) allows me to wait until all children have finished, such as waitpid(-1, &status). But how can I wait until all **background** processes are finished? Someone suggested that I can use the same waitpid (in a loop?) to achieve this but I don't see how.

To be clear, I'm implementing a shell, and need to add a new built-in command wait, which waits until all background jobs have terminated before returning to the prompt.

I read somewhere else on SO that "You will also want to call waitpid() with the WNOHANG option regularly - say, immediately before you display the shell prompt. This will allow you to detect when the background process has exited or stopped " But again, child != background. So even that I don't believe.

---

Edit:

I ended up just doing while(wait(NULL) > 0); and that's it, it worked. But what I'm still confused about is don't I WANT to make a distinction between foreground and background because the wait I'm implementing only waits for the background processes, and all children are equal in the eye of wait() or waitpid().

So again, the children I'm waiting for by using wait() or waitpid() aren't necessarily background processes. Am I wrong?

Comment: C has no concept of "background processes".  Background vs. foreground is a shell job-control thing.  So what do *you* mean by it?

Comment: I am implementing a shell, so you are exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you ask in the context of implementing a shell, and evidently your shell supports enough job control to have a concept of background processes, it is reasonable to suppose that your implementation will have a table in which it tracks background jobs.  That table can and should track the PID of the process associated with each job.

Having those PIDs in hand, you can `waitpid()` for specific background jobs until there are no more in the table, or you can `waitpid(-1)` to collect 
any and every job, in a loop, until there are no more background jobs in the table.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the waitpid(-1) loop? I assume you mean waitpid(-1) with the WNOHANG option.

Comment: @ajfbiw.s, it depends on the semantics you want.  Your question asks to *wait* until all background jobs finish, which suggests blocking -- i.e. *not* using `WNOHANG`.  In fact, there is no point to using `WNOHANG` if every path to breaking out of the loop requires you to collect at least one child.

Comment: I ended up just doing while(wait(NULL) > 0); and that's it, it worked. But what I'm still confused about is don't I WANT to make a distinction between foreground and background because the wait I'm implementing only waits for the background processes, and all children are equal in the eye of wait() or waitpid().

Comment: So again, the children I'm waiting for by using wait() or waitpid() aren't necessarily background processes. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ajfbiw.s, as I wrote earlier, foreground vs. background is a distinction imposed by the shell.  `wait()` and `waitpid()` have no concept of it.  Note, however, that when the shell itself is in the foreground, *all* its managed jobs are necessarily in the background.  If you need to perform this task only under such circumstances then waiting for all child processes is probably ok.

Comment: @ajfbiw.s, your main risk with such a strategy is if the shell is running in parallel with a separate foreground job.  In that case, you do need to ensure that you don't *require* that job to be collected as part of the task, but if it happens to finish while one or more background jobs are still running, then it is not necessarily a problem to collect it, too.

Comment: I get it now (I think). Since all of the shell's managed jobs are necessarily in the background, it is ok to wait for all of the children - all of the children are in the background, so waiting for all children to finish is the same as waiting for all background to finish in this case. I get this part. However, why is there a risk of also waiting for a separate job that's running in parallel with my shell? Wait() only waits for children and the parallel job in question cannot be a children. Correct?

Comment: @ajfbiw.s, all jobs managed by your shell are necessarily associated with child processes of the shell, including the foreground job.  If for some reason you implemented job management in such a way that some functions of the shell itself can run in parallel with the foreground job, then that's where you would need to take extra care.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement background process (and job control) and catch their termination (at least) you must set a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`, and call `wait(-1)` inside it. This will let your shell receive asynchronous notifications of background processes termination. You may have a look at [Catching SIGCHLD](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-4750/signals-7/index.html) for example and discussion about this.